# SOLVED - Moving Magento 2.2.2 development environment to production environment

Tags: magento2.2.2, development

I'm trying create and manage my Magento project with 2 domain on my webserver. I'm using Magento 2.2.2.
1. dev.test.com => for development. 
2. test.com => for production.
My idea is using github repo to push my update from development and then pull update to production but I have a problem now. I already created 2 domain on my webserver and tested it. Then I install and start coding on dev.test.com domain. Then I copied all files and folders in dev.test.com to test.com domain and modified env.php file to match with database and database user, then I use php bin/magento setup:rollback to rollback database in dev.test.com to test.com and modify web_unsecure_url to match with test.com. Final step, I clear pub/static/* , var/generated/* ,var/viewpreprocessed/*, var/cache/* and do magento cache:clean.

Then I go to test.com to test but it gives me http_errors 500. What should I do to make it work
Does anybody have idea for this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this error before, the problem is in the files permissions.

Please follow this link to set the right permissions.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

```
cd <your Magento install dir>
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;
find var vendor generated pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

you can also try to execute **upgrade command** to see if there are any errors or missed PHP extensions

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. I missed set permission step. Working perfect now.