# Magento - Error 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: magento2, error, server-setup, http-error-500

I just finished with this whole website and all is working fine, I want to install french pack via ssh, I had problem with memory so I used root access to install and the installation was successful,

when I turned back to the website I couldn't access and I get this

> Error 500 - Internal Server Error An error was encountered while processing your request. Typically this is a temporary condition. Please contact the web site owner for further assistance.

when I delete `.htaccess` I can access the front page only with no css, If I click on a link I got 404 Error

the module doesn't appear when I check modules status using

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

so I can't disable or delete it, even if I rename the vendor/imaginaerum folder nothing change

I also ran

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
chmod 777 -R downloader var media
```

to fix if any file permission but no result also

the French package I've installed 
http://imaginaerum.github.io/magento2-language-fr-fr/

Comment: Try to retart your server, if still it doesn't work remove this translation module then restart the server again

Comment: I just restarted my VPS server bust still same error
I deleted the module folder under vendor/imaginaerum also

Comment: Which french pack did you install? What does your server log says?

Comment: this is the pack I installed 
http://imaginaerum.github.io/magento2-language-fr-fr/

Comment: this is the log message 
public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75430/helping-cdzwebdev

Comment: No, dont remove the folder directly form a server !, you have to execute this command : `php bin/magento module:uninstall Vendor_Module `  then deploy the static content like this : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Try do a compile and deploy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the Apache that he has has no `module_version` check and the `<IfVersion>` tags in the htaccess where not recognized. We temporarily removed them and he will see this with his host

EDIT :

After some more digging we installed mod_version on the apache and now it works

Answer (score -1):

Most of 500 Errors are file permission issues.

I had this error before, the problem is in the files permissions.

Please follow this link to set the right permissions.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

```
cd <your Magento install dir>
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;
find var vendor generated pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

you can also try to execute **upgrade command** to see if there are any errors or missed PHP extensions

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

this also was answered in this question
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/219944/31830

Comment: 500 errors are NOT definitely permissions based at all. 500 errors can be a whole spectrum of server related issues, .htaccess issues etc etc