# Problem after migrating magento 2 to a new server

Tags: magento2, migration

I started developing a magento 2 website a dedicated server with an IP lets say (85.85.85.85) with Centos 7 and when I finished my development I downloaded the whole html folder (magento root) with a mysql backup and I reformatted my dedicated server and i putted Centos 7 with Plesk. I followed an article about migrating my website and i uploaded the files restored the database, connect the database with the files, changed the core_config urls and when I hit my domain on browser its says me "File not found.". Some of my plesk error logs can be shown here(1.http://prntscr.com/jdtyyw 2.http://prntscr.com/jdtz8g 3.http://prntscr.com/jdtzkc 4.http://prntscr.com/jdtzox) 
If anyone knows what happens here please help me unstuck from this,
Every help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

-----EDIT-----
I corrected the file permissions
When I run the command line

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

its says me this message

```
[Exception]
Warning: file_get_contents (/var/www/vhosts/domainname/httpdocs/var/di/setup.ser) : 
failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/domainname/httpdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader/Compiled.php on line 28
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a permission issue,

Please follow this link to set the right permissions.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

there is an answer here

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/219944/31830

Comment: I tried to use php bin/magento setup:upgrade and it showed me this: [Exception]Warning: file_get_contents (/var/www/vhosts/domainname/httpdocs/var/di/setup.ser) : failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/domainname/httpdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader/Compiled.php on line 28

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: Did you follow the link above? From magento website?